# I am sending sending POST request but Laravel picks up GET

Tags: php, laravel

I am submitting request to my API '/api/authenticate'

```
Route::post('authenticate', 'api\authenticateController@authenticate');
```

Each time I send "POST" request server thinks that I am sending "GET" request.

In the $/public/index.php I have added the following line to dump what method I am using:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/api/authenticate") {
        dd(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
}
```

And I keep getting

```
#method: "GET"
```

I have run:

```
composer dumpautoload
composer update
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Yet nothing helped... what might be the problem?

p.s. works find on the localhost and for tests i have been using PostMan; and below is a screenshot of me performing submit using postman : http://prntscr.com/efjwb7

Here is the code for the $\public\index.php file; you can see where I did the dd()...

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/api/authenticate") {
    dd(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
}

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Quick note -
I added var_dump($_POST) at the very top of the index.php file and var_dump happens to be empty. * it seem to only effect routes under "api".

---

Update - here is a sample cURL call from Postman

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/api/authenticate",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_key\"\r\n\r\njLiHWIwfi3KwGCt7OhQtFa8AAg4Ca\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user\"\r\n\r\npro\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\npassword\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Show your form code.

Comment: use 'method' => 'POST' in your sending form

Comment: you might want to debug with postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: postman is what i use.

Comment: I have added code for the $/public/index.php page if anyone is interested

Comment: Post your __form__ code. None of this helps without seeing the form. Is it sent through a regular form or an ajax call?

Comment: this is a screenshot of the body which I am sending http://prntscr.com/efka93 ; just to clarify this is an api call.

Comment: That is not the code. If it's an API call, then show the code making that call.

Comment: I use postman to deal with an API call; I have attached sample cURL code from postman to the main message..

Comment: Try `CURLOPT_POST => 1` in your curl_setopt_array.

Answer (score -1):

What's about configs which are connected with slashes? I had  the same problem, when I send the request like "site.com/url" and server redirected me to the "site.com/url/". So, I think you need to check the ngninx/apache configs.